# Cmake error: set command does not like the same .h files from a previous set command

Tags: c++, cmake, set

I have two set commands in my CMake.txt file. I have something like:

```
set(GUI_SOURCE_FILES         
    src/UINode/main.cpp  
    src/UINode/b.cpp  
    src/UINode/c.cpp  
    src/UINode/d.cpp  
)

set(GUI_HEADER_FILES        
    src/UINode/b.h 
    src/UINode/c.h  
    src/UINode/d.h 

)
```

This works fine and the executable is good. Now I want to have another group of set commands that need to included the above and add new .h and .cpp files. I am not sure if this is possible but I know that I cannot do something like:

```
set(GUIA_SOURCE_FILES         
    src/UINode/different_main.cpp  
    src/UINode/b.cpp  
    src/UINode/c.cpp  
    src/UINode/d.cpp  
        src/anotherpath/e.cpp
)

set(GUIA_HEADER_FILES        
    src/UINode/b.h 
    src/UINode/c.h  
    src/UINode/d.h
        src/anotherpath/e.h 

)
```

EDIT 1: Thanks for the reply user2799037! I now have something like:

```
set(COMMON_SOURCE_FILES         
src/UINode/a.cpp  
src/UINode/b.cpp  
src/UINode/c.cpp 
)

set(COMMON_HEADER_FILES        
 src/UINode/a.h 
src/UINode/b.h  
src/UINode/c.h  
)
```

I then use them by:

```
set(GUI_SOURCE_FILES         
src/UINode/main_GUI.cpp  
${COMMON_SOURCE_FILES}
)

set(GUI_HEADER_FILES        
${COMMON_HEADER_FILES}  
)
```

and do 
QT4_WRAP_CPP(GUI_HEADER_FILES_HPP ${GUI_HEADER_FILES})
followed by the 
rosbuild_add_executable.

For the next part I do:

```
set(GUIA_SOURCE_FILES         
src/commands/main_GUI1.cpp  
${COMMON_SOURCE_FILES}
)

set(GUIA_HEADER_FILES        
${COMMON_HEADER_FILES}   
src/pathplanning/anotherheader.h
)
```

but I get an error when i do:
    QT4_WRAP_CPP(GUIA_HEADER_FILES_HPP ${GUIA_HEADER_FILES})

'CMake Error: Attempt to add a custom rule to output'

Comment: These are just the "SET" commands.  You can set variables to anything you want.  The problem must be happening when you try to use these variables in other commands.  Show us those, along with the full error message.

Comment: Are you sure this `CMake Error: Attempt to add a custom rule to output` is related to the posted code? Without a line number, it's hard to tell. Try adding `${}` or even `"${}"` around all variables evaluations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do something like that

```
set(COMMON_SOURCE_FILES
    src/UINode/b.cpp
    src/UINode/c.cpp
    src/UINode/d.cpp
)

set(COMMON_HEADER_FILES
    src/UINode/b.h
    src/UINode/c.h
    src/UINode/d.h
)
```

and use these for you more specific variables:

```
set(GUI_SOURCE_FILES         
    ${COMMON_SOURCE_FILES }
   src/anotherpath/main.cpp
)

set(GUIA_SOURCE_FILES         
    ${COMMON_SOURCE_FILES }
   src/anotherpath/different_main.cpp
)
```

Analog for the headers. With this approach you avoid having two list which can get out of sync.